# Setting up nginx for multiple reverse proxies

Tags: nginx

This might be a basic question as I'm fairly new to nginx.

I have two docker-containers running, one on port 8000 and one on 8080.

In essence what I want to achieve is running the main container on the server IP and the second container under a subdirectory of the domain.

such as
ip/* reverse proxies to port 8000 and ip/LLS/* goes to port 8080.

Note: Due to a bug in the software in the docker-container I have to specify a port. I also edited out the IP because I rather not have the IP available online.

This is my current server config to do this.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name IP;
#return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# nginx/sites-available/fdp.conf

location /LLS/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass http://IP:8000;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass http://IP:8080;
}
}
```

With this setup requests to / go correct but /LLS/ fail; most likely it tries to look up the domain on port 8080.

How do I change the config to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://IP:8080/;
}

    location ~ /LLS/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://IP:8000;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this still does not work and the request is picked up by the first server.